# Keep UI updated while script is running

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I'm using a google map via Google's maps api v3. I need to add an overlay for each menu-item. Everytime, the item is clicked, a new overlay/heatmap is loaded. This works, but the loading of the markers/heatmap-points freezes the UI.

Is there any positility to prevent this like updating in a background-thread? I know that JavaScript doesn't really support threading, but do you know some hacks?

Comment: Ok, but I can't even add a loader-gif, because the UI isn't updated at any point of time in the changing-time. Maybe some hack for this?

Comment: Yeah, add the gif, and invoke the rest of the code with setTimeout(..,0). This clears the current call stack, lets the browser do any rendering and then calls whatever you passed to setTimeout. (The gif still wont animate if your code keeps the browser busy)

Answer (score 1):

You can try researching WebWorkers.

Or you can split your work into separate chunks and call each chunk after the next using setTimeout with a timeout of 0.

```
setTimeout( function() { executeNextChunk(); }, 0 )
```

This gives the browser time to do other stuff in between invocations.